# Order get_terms() By Custom Field

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, terms, order

I want to order my categories like I order my pages. I've added an extra field called *Order* to my taxonomy, but how do I order my terms by this value?

Adding and Saving my Order Value:

```
/** Add New Field To Category **/
function extra_category_fields( $tag ) {
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id" );
?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="meta-order"><?php _e('Category Order'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <div id="catOrder">
            <input type="text" name="cat_meta[order]" size="3" style="width:5%;" value="<?php echo (isset($cat_meta['order'])) ? $cat_meta['order'] : '0'; ?>" />
        </div>
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Categories are ordered Smallest to Largest'); ?></span>
    </td> 
</tr>
<?php
}
add_action('protax_edit_form_fields','extra_category_fields');  

/** Save Category Meta **/
function save_extra_category_fileds( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['cat_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
        $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['cat_meta']);
            foreach ($cat_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['cat_meta'][$key])){
                $cat_meta[$key] = $_POST['cat_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        //save the option array
        update_option( "category_$t_id", strip_tags($cat_meta) );
    }
}
add_action ( 'edited_protax', 'save_extra_category_fileds');
```

Normally I could retrieve this value such as:

```
$categories = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'protax'));
foreach($categories as $cat){
    $tmp = get_option('category_'.$cat->cat_ID);
    echo $tmp['order'];
}
```

Is it possible to order by this custom value? Is there a better way to manually order my categories?

Comment: `get_categories` as an option to order by `term_group`. Term group is a field in `wp_terms` table that AFAIK is not used by WordPress. So you can use the extra field to set the term_group and then use `'orderby' => 'term_group'` in `$args` array for `get_categories`.

Comment: :/ I'm not sure I follow. When or where do I set `term_group`?

Comment: Something along these lines, in my save function: `$wpdb->update($prefix.'terms', array('term_group' => $cat_meta));` ?

Comment: `$wpdb->update($wpdb->terms, array('term_group' => $cat_meta['order']), array('term_id'=>$term_id));` you need a `WHERE` clause and `$cat_meta['order']` not all the `$cat_meta` array

Comment: @G.M. You're right, it is saved in the database, juts not showing up in searches as it's a column - my mistake. It's showing all the correct values there too. Displaying my terms are still going through alphabetically though: `get_terms('protax', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'order_by' => 'term_group', 'order' => 'ASC'));` with `ASC`, `DESC`, and when I remove `order` entirely. It is including `term_group` with each category though so I have access to it.

Comment: In [codex for `get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Parameters) orderby term_group is cited with any advice, but in [codex for get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Parameters) is said _"not fully implemented (avoid using)"_ so isn't only your problem... sorry for your time loose, I remember I've used it with no problems...

Comment: No no, thank you for your help! I got it to work with get_categories - I was misspelling orderby: Solution is in my Question - again thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Please remove the solution from your question and post it as an answer (yes, you can answer your own questions).

Comment: @its_me I know, I just didn't want to answer a question G. M. solved xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOLUTION - Updated: 03/03/2015** - Thanks to /u/G.M.

The below adds a new field to the Term Edit Page and saves the value into the un-used ( for the moment anyway ) `term_group` field which can then be used to order terms. In the below hooks ( actions ) you'll need to replace `TAXONOMY_SLUG` with your actual taxonomy slug.

```
/**
 * Append Fields To Term Edit Page
 * @param Term Object $term
 * @param string $taxonomy
 */
function term_order_field( $term, $taxonomy ) {
  ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top">
            <label for="meta-order"><?php _e( 'Category Order' ); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="_term_order" size="3" style="width:5%;" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $term->term_group ) ) ? $term->term_group : '0'; ?>" />
            <span class="description"><?php _e( 'Categories are ordered Smallest to Largest' ); ?></span>
        </td> 
    </tr>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'TAXONOMY_SLUG_edit_form_fields', 'term_order_field', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Save Term Order
 * @param int $term_id
 */
function save_term_order( $term_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( isset( $_POST['_term_order'] ) ) {
        $wpdb->update( 
            $wpdb->terms,
            array(
                'term_group' => $_POST['_term_order']
            ),
            array( 
                'term_id'    => $term_id
            )
        );
    }
} // END Function
add_action( 'edited_TAXONOMY_SLUG', 'save_term_order' );
```

**Add Term Order cell to Term List**

```
/**
 * Add Column To Show 'Term Order' Field
 * @param array $columns
 * @return array $columns
 */
function term_order_header( $columns ) {
    $columns['order'] = '<center>Order</center>';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-TAXONOMY_SLUG_columns', 'term_order_header' );

/**
 * Give 'Term Order' Column A Value `term_group`
 * @param string $empty
 * @param string $col_name
 * @param int $term_id
 * @return string
 */
function term_order_header_val( $empty = '', $col_name, $term_id ) {
    if( isset( $_GET['taxonomy'] ) && 'order' == $col_name ) {
        $term = get_term( $term_id, $_GET['taxonomy'] );
        return "<center>{$term->term_group}</center>";
    } else {
        return '0';
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_TAXONOMY_SLUG_custom_column', 'term_order_header_val', 10, 3 );
```

**Hook Documentation**

- [action `{$taxonomy}_edit_form_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_edit_form_fields/)
- [action `edited_{$taxonomy}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_taxonomy/)
- [filter `manage_{$screen->id}_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_screen-id_columns/)
- [filter `manage_{$this->screen->taxonomy}_custom_column`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-taxonomy_custom_column/)

---

Below is an out-dated solution that works better if you have multiple Term Meta Values you would like to save. If you only need to save Term Order, the above solution is best.

```
/** Add New Field To Category **/
function extra_category_fields( $tag ) {
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id" );
?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="meta-order"><?php _e('Category Order'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <div id="catOrder">
            <input type="text" name="cat_meta[order]" size="3" style="width:5%;" value="<?php echo (isset($cat_meta['order'])) ? $cat_meta['order'] : '0'; ?>" />
        </div>
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Categories are ordered Smallest to Largest'); ?></span>
    </td> 
</tr>
<?php
}
add_action('protax_edit_form_fields','extra_category_fields');  

/** Save Category Meta **/
function save_extra_category_fileds( $term_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( isset( $_POST['cat_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
        $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['cat_meta']);
            foreach ($cat_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['cat_meta'][$key])){
                $cat_meta[$key] = $_POST['cat_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        update_option( "category_$t_id", $cat_meta );
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->terms, array('term_group' => $cat_meta['order']), array('term_id'=>$term_id));
    }
}
add_action ( 'edited_protax', 'save_extra_category_fileds');
```

Calling it:

```
$procats = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'protax', 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_group'));
```

**Edit** - You're also able to order them in the admin panel by using this filter:

```
function change_term_order( $orderby, $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if ( is_admin() && 'protax' !== $taxonomies[0] )
        return $orderby;

    $orderby = 'term_group';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_orderby', 'change_term_order', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: So I remember well :) +1 to reward your tenacity and my suggestion...

Comment: Thanks for this. It convinced me to create a custom post type and link posts to taxonomy terms that hold the custom fields, as opposed to adding custom fields to the taxonomy itself. Without being able to use the loop for taxonomy terms the same way it works for posts, this would have been a real headache.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$terms_hearing = merge_tax_and_custom_field(
    get_terms([
        'taxonomy'   => 'hearing',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ]),
    'abbr'
);

sort_tax_by_custom_field($terms_hearing, 'abbr');

// function will allow to merge taxonomy result with custom taxonomy terms
function merge_tax_and_custom_field($terms, $field)
{
    // merge custom field into original taxonomy object
    foreach ($terms as $index => $term) {
        // grabbing custom field data
        $data = get_option('taxonomy_term_' . $term->term_id)[$field];

        // adding data field into term object as property
        $terms[$index]->{$field} = $data;
    }

    return $terms;
}

// sort field by custom field value
function sort_tax_by_custom_field($terms, $field)
{
    usort($terms, function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a->abbr, $b->abbr);
    });

    return $terms;
}
```