# Using ACF custom field for custom post type to order categories

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, categories, php

I'm trying to use [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161227/1685) to order categories based on their Advanced Custom Fields custom field: `track_order`.

I'm able to get the UL to print fine and show the custom field numbers

[image: custom categories order image]

but I'm unable to pass the new sorted terms to the `foreach` loop for the individual categories.

```
    <?php
    //$terms = get_terms("crb_issues");
    $terms = get_categories('taxonomy=tracks');
    $issue_archive = array( ); // creates an array for all terms inside of crb_issues tax using the custom field "issue_date" as the key
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $issue_date = get_field( 'track_order', $term );
        $issue_archive[$issue_date] = $term->name;
    }

    krsort( $issue_archive, SORT_NUMERIC ); //sorts the issue_archive array from high to low

    foreach ( $issue_archive as $issue_date => $term_name ) {
        echo "<li>" . $term_name . " " . $issue_date . "</li>"; //displays the term name and customfield issue_date
        if (++$i == 4) break; //Stops the foreach after 4
    }
    ?>

    <?php foreach($terms as $term): ?>
```

Which gives me this order for my template layout:

[image: not using order I want]

How can I get the order being generated by the ACF custom field to be passed to the `foreach` loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to "pass" the order to your third `foreach` - just loop over `$issue_archive` again instead of `$terms`.

Comment: that didn't work, the other solution is working well, though. thx

Answer (score 0):

After more sleuthing, found an appropriate solution:

```
    <?php
    // Solution for sorting by ACF custom-field for tracks categories
    // http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/sorting-categories-list-by-custom-field/
    $categories = get_categories('taxonomy=tracks');
    $sorted_cats = array();
    foreach($categories as $cat){
    //$ordr = get_field('track_order', 'tracks_'.$cat>term_id); //wasn't working so used the line below
        $ordr = get_field( 'track_order', $cat );
        $sorted_cats[$ordr] = $cat;
    }
    krsort($sorted_cats);//ksort orders ascending, krsort reverses order (i.e. biggest to smallest)

    /* Test to print out order... not sure why cat name not showing...
    foreach ( $sorted_cats as $ordr => $term_name ) {
        echo "<li>" . $ordr->name . " " . $ordr . "</li>"; //displays the term name and customfield issue_date
        if (++$i == 4) break; //Stops the foreach after 4
    }*/
    ?>
```

**I'd like to get the test `<li>` to show the category name, but I can't get it to work. All that prints is the ACF order number. Any help on that part is greatly appreciated.**

Here is a screenshot showing how the categories are now ordering correctly (big to low with Test Track = 200):

[image]