# Ordering get_terms with ACF not displaying all terms

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields, terms

I'm making a shortcode to return all the terms in this taxonomy. The terms are sorted with krsort by the custom field 'height' made from ACF. I'm following this [answer from here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/205525/66224).

The problem is it's only displaying 8 terms and there's 15 in total. All of these terms have the custom field filled out and have posts for them so I'm not sure.

I need this object array because I will be displaying other parameters in foreach.

```
function taxonomies_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',
        ), $atts 
    ));
    $args = array( 
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    );
    $terms = get_terms( $args );
    $newterms = array(); 
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $order = get_field( 'height', $term );                
        $newterms[$order] = (object) array(
            'name' => $term->name,
            'slug' => $term->slug,
            'term_id' => $term->term_id
        );
    }
    ksort( $newterms, SORT_NUMERIC );
    foreach ( $newterms as $newterm ) {     
        $html .= '<a href="#' . $newterm->slug . '">' . $newterm->name . '</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'taxonomies', 'taxonomies_shortcode' );
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing terms, maybe try to show all terms, event those that are not assigned to a post. By default, wordpress does not get terms that are not in a post.

```
get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));
```