# Sorting get_terms, ACF is automatically removing duplicates

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, terms

I read over the ACF & WordPress documentation and both do not mention why/when/how duplicate values are removed from an array when sorting taxonomy terms by custom fields.

I learned that ACF does this from this [StackExchange answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/217423/66224). But in this example code it is not sorting correctly and it doesn't work with krsort. With anything besides usort it gives the error: "krsort() expects parameter 2 to be long". Could anyone help here?

Shortcode I am trying to make with the example code:

```
function ranker_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => '',
        ), $atts 
    ));
    $args = array( 
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    );

    $sorted = array();
    $terms  = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

    if( $terms ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $sorted[]  = array(
                'height' => get_field( 'height', $term ), // Get field from ACF
                'name'  => $term->name,
            );
        }

        krsort( $sorted, SORT_NUMERIC );

        foreach( $sorted as $t ) {
            $html .= $t['height'] . ', ' . $t['name'] . '<br>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'ranker', 'ranker_shortcode' );
```

**Solved + Answer:**
Thanks to Pieter Goosen I got this working. I edited his answer somewhat to include more fields.

```
/**
 * Shortcode to sort taxonomy terms by meta field. Utilizes Advanced Custom Fields plugin.
 */
function sort_term_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Defualt attributes
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( 
        [
            'taxonomy' => '',
        ], $atts 
    );

    $html = '';

    $taxonomy = filter_var( $attributes['taxonomy'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( ! $taxonomy ) 
        return $html; // sanitize shortcode attributes

    if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) 
        return $html; // check shortcode attributes exists

    $terms  = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    if( ! $terms ) 
        return $html; // check terms exists

    $newterms = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $height  = get_field( 'height', $term );
        $newterms[$height][]  = array(
            'name'        => $term->name,
            'count'       => $term->count,
            'description' => wpautop( $term->description ),
            'link'        => esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ),
            'weight'      => get_field( 'weight', $term )
        );
    }

    krsort( $newterms, SORT_NUMERIC ); // biggest to smallest sort

    $c = 0;
    foreach( $newterms as $key => $value ) {
        foreach ( $value as $v ) {
            $c++;
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $v['avatar'], 't_thumb' );
            $html .= '<div class="panel panel-default">' . "\n";
                $html .= '<div class="panel-heading">' . "\n";
                    $html .= '<h3 class="panel-title">' . $c . ' &nbsp; <strong>' . $v['name'] . '</strong>,&nbsp; ' . $key . ', ' . $v['weight'] . 'lbs.</h3>' . "\n";
                $html .= '</div>' . "\n";
                $html .= '<div class="media panel-body">' . "\n";
                    $html .= '<a class="media-left" href="' . $v['link'] . '"><img src="' . $thumb[0] . '"></a>' . "\n";
                    $html .= '<div class="media-body">' . "\n";
                        $html .= $v['description'] . "\n";
                    $html .= '</div>' . "\n";
                $html .= '</div>' . "\n";
            $html .= '</div>' . "\n";
        }
    }
    return $html;

}
add_shortcode( 'sort_term', 'sort_term_shortcode' );
```

Comment: ACF specific questions are off-topic.

Comment: @MarkKaplun There are definitely much more generic stuff which makes this on topic as ACF specific support ;-)

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it is about the stupid way ACF stores values associated with tems @PieterGoosen

Comment: but maybe my mind not working properly

Comment: It's actually a krsort/sorting issue. Sorting removes the duplicate values. Not just ACF @MarkKaplun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not allow duplicate keys, the previous key/value pair is simply replaced with the current key/value pair. Anyways, lets look at your code and how we will solve it

You have a few issues here

- You should not be using `extract()`, ever. It was removed from core a few years ago for very specific reasons. Please read [@toscho's answer regarding `extract()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99604/31545)
- Always sanitize and validate any user submitted data, even if that data is coming from you. User input data may contain malicious code which a hacker can use to get access to your site
- `$html` is an undefined variable in your code, which is a bug. If you have [debug turned on](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), you would get an explicit notice about that. Always define a variable before trying to use it, and always have debug set to true on your local test install
- You are using `get_terms()` wrongly. The second parameter takes an array of parameters which does not include the taxonomy. The taxonomy is passed as first parameter
- You are using ACF and ACF functions which will crash your site should ACF be uninstalled. Always do a check to make sure that external functions exists before suing it to avoid WSOD. Just a tip here, as from WordPress 4.4, you can now make use of the term metadata table to store additional info related to a term and then use that data to sort terms by. ACF is almost always a pain in the butt to remove when you no longer need the plugin
- [`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) is definitely the wrong sorting function to use in your current code. `usort()` should have being the correct sorting function to use. In our new code, `krsort()` would work perfectly

Lets look at better workaround. I accept that you need to display terms sorted by ACF field. You can try the following: (***NOTE:*** The code below is untested and might be buggy. Also, I don't know the ACF plugin, make sure about my usage of `get_field()`)

```
add_shortcode( 'ranker', 'ranker_shortcode' );
function ranker_shortcode( $atts ) 
{
    // Define our defualt attributes
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( 
        [
            'taxonomy' => '',
        ], $atts 
    );

    // Set our $html variable as empty string
    $html = '';

    // Sanitize and validate our taxonomy to avoid bugs later on. Return $html should anything fail
    $taxonomy = filter_var( $attributes['taxonomy'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( !$taxonomy )
        return $html;

    if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
        return $html;

    // We made it to hear, check if the ACF plugin is activated and that get_field() exists
    if ( !function_exists( 'get_field' ) )
        return $html;

    // Great, we made it to here, our checks checked out, lets continue
    $terms  = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    // Make sure we have terms, no need to check for WP_Error object because we know the taxonomy exists
    if( !$terms )
        return $html;

    // We have terms, lets loop through them and build our array
    $sorted = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        // Get our field value and make sure we have a field value, if not, just continue
        $field  = get_field( 'height', $term ); // Make sure we can pass the term object, don't know ACF

        if ( !$field )
            continue;

        // Our term have a field, lets build the array
        $sorted[$field][]  = $term->name;
    }

    // Lets sort the array DESC according to array key, which is our $field value
    krsort( $sorted, SORT_NUMERIC ); // Make sure here that your field is actually numeric to avoid bugs

    if ( !$sorted )
        return $html;

    // We are done, lets build our string and return it
    foreach( $sorted as $key=>$value ) {
        foreach ( $value as $v ) {
            $html .= $key . ', ' . $v . '<br>';
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems to be just returning 2 0's with a line break though. I'm wondering if it's returning all empty taxonomies? I had to slightly change the ACF area to: 
get_field( 'height', $taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id  )

Comment: Add `?><pre><?php var_dump($sorted); ?></pre><?php` after `krsort( $sorted, SORT_NUMERIC );` and see what the output is

Comment: You're right! I removed the conditional statements just to test it, but of course I screwed something up in the process. I just ran it with everything you had and it's good to go. I will note though on the ACF field that ',' needs to be changed to ';' for proper PHP syntax. (In case anyone gets tripped by that if they find this through Google). Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked, will correct the syntax error. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: If you don't mind can you add an example to your answer for more than 2 fields (height, name)? How about 3 or more (ex. height, name, description)? If it's tedious don't worry about it, you taught me a lot already.

Comment: I think I got multiple fields working now, so ignore my last message. I will update my OP with everything so people can use it.

Comment: Good morning, glad you were able to sort it out. I see you asked a question with multiple fields, it will be a good idea to post your answer to that question ;-)