# Category specific order

Tags: categories

I am trying to figure out how to display the categories in a specific order. Let's say my category IDs are in the following order: 1,3,4,2,5

I want to display the categories in that sequence. Here is the following code I have so far but it isn't working:

```
$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'front_order_id',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 0,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => 1,
    'include'                  => '1,3,4,2,5',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
    'pad_counts'               => false
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: Usually if I need my categories or terms in a specific order I'll refer to one of my questions which allows me to set a custom field to each term where I can define an order (similar to Pages page-order attribute) I can then order by `term_group`. - [View Question / Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117147/order-get-terms-by-custom-field/117172#117172). The order is entirely custom and can easily be changed in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I don't really know of a solution within Wordpress to sort the way you need. I think the best is to make use of php sorting to sort your returned array as needed

## Here is how:

1. Get the array of category info as you normally do

   ```
   $categories = get_categories($args);
   ```

`$categories` will hold an array of the five categories returned from the database

2. You now need to create an array with your desired sort order

   ```
   $keys = [1,3,4,2,5];
   ```
3. You are now going to combine `$keys` and `$categories` with [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). We will use the values of `Skeys` for the keys for our new combined array

   ```
   $categories_rearranged = array_combine( $keys, $categories );
   ```
4. At this stage, your array will not be naturally sorted, so with the use of [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), sort your array so that it is ordered naturally

   ```
   ksort($categories_rearranged);
   ```
5. `$categories_rearranged` will now be the array that you will make use of and will be passed to your `foreach` loop

   ```
   foreach ( $categories_rearranged as $category ) {
      echo $category->name;
   }
   ```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The codex is there to help you. Look at [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) and in particular to the following parameters

> **orderby**
>
> (string) Sort categories alphabetically or by unique category ID. The default is sort by name. Valid values:
>
> - id
> - name - default
> - slug
> - count
> - term_group

You can see you are passing an invalid parameter to `orderby`

The `include` and `exclude` parameters cannot be used together as well

Comment: The categories I want are 1,3,4,2,5 in that specific order not ASC or desc.  Wordpress will instead display the categories in this order 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Please see my edit, I misread your OP. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what you're getting?

If you're not getting anything, this is probably why:

```
'child_of' => 0
```

Also, what's this?

```
'orderby' => 'front_order_id',
```

Also, this doesn't change the order:

```
'include' => '1,3,4,2,5',
```

check this out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: orderby front_order_id is a custom field using the following plugin

https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box

Comment: @stargatesg1 that info should be in your question. Please make sure that all relevant info is posted **in** your question. This will ensure that no one wastes their time answering irrelevant or erronous info. Thank you